# I am getting an error about displaying an image without rebuilding the page

Tags: database, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, build

I am making a note app with flutter. I have a page called `createUpdateNoteView`. In this page, I can create a new note or i can update and existing note. Recently, i added a new feature to this page. I added a floating action button that provides user to upload an image from gallery. When the user clicked this button choose an image from gallery. After then, this picture uploads to the firebase firestore and returns an image url.

```
class CloudNote {
  final String documentId;
  final String ownerUserId;
  final String text;
  String? imageUrl;

  CloudNote({
    required this.documentId,
    required this.ownerUserId,
    required this.text,
    this.imageUrl,
  });

  CloudNote.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
      : documentId = snapshot.id,
        ownerUserId = snapshot.data()[ownerUserIdFieldName],
        text = snapshot.data()[textFieldName] as String,
        imageUrl = snapshot.data()[imageUrlFieldName];
}
```

Then i display it with an image.network() property. Now my problem is that i can succesfully upload this to the firebase.

```
Future<String> pickAnImageAndGetUrl() async {
    ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    XFile? file = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (file != null) {
      String uniqueFileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
      Reference referenceRoot = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
      Reference referenceDirImages = referenceRoot.child('images');
      Reference referenceImageToUpload =
          referenceDirImages.child(uniqueFileName);

      try {
        await referenceImageToUpload.putFile(File(file.path));

        imageUrl = await referenceImageToUpload.getDownloadURL();
        return imageUrl;
      } catch (error) {
        throw Exception();
      }
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  Future<void> addImageToNote({
    required String documentId,
    required String imageUrl,
  }) async {
    try {
      await notes.doc(documentId).update({imageUrlFieldName: imageUrl});
    } catch (e) {
      throw CouldNotAddImageToNoteException();
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteImageInTheNote({
    required String documentId,
    required String imageUrl,
  }) async {
    try {
      final imageRef = storage.refFromURL(imageUrl);

      await notes.doc(documentId).update({imageUrlFieldName: null});
      await imageRef.delete();
    } catch (e) {
      throw CouldNotDeletImageException();
    }
  }
```

However, i cannot see it immideately. I have to go back to the home screen and click to note again. That's my problem. How can i display the image as soon as i uploaded to the firebase without going back to homescreen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:holdit/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:holdit/utilities/dialogs/cannot_share_empty_note_dialog.dart';
import 'package:holdit/utilities/dialogs/delete_image_dialog.dart';
import 'package:holdit/utilities/generics/get_arguments.dart';
import 'package:holdit/services/cloud/cloud_note.dart';
import 'package:holdit/services/cloud/firebase_cloud_storage.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';

class CreateUpdateNoteView extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateUpdateNoteView({super.key});

  @override
  State<CreateUpdateNoteView> createState() => _CreateUpdateNoteViewState();
}

class _CreateUpdateNoteViewState extends State<CreateUpdateNoteView> {
  bool _imageDeleted = false;
  bool _isLoadingImage = false;
  bool _isUploadingImage = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _noteService = FirebaseCloudStorage();
    _textController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  CloudNote? _note;
  late final FirebaseCloudStorage _noteService;
  late final TextEditingController _textController;

  Future<CloudNote> createOrGetExistingNote(BuildContext context) async {
    final widgetNote = context.getArgument<CloudNote>();

    if (widgetNote != null) {
      _note = widgetNote;

      _textController.text = widgetNote.text;
      return widgetNote;
    }
    final existingNote = _note;
    if (existingNote != null) {
      return existingNote;
    }

    final currentUser = AuthService.firebase().currentUser!;
    final userId = currentUser.id;
    final newNote = await _noteService.createNewNote(ownerUserId: userId);
    _note = newNote;
    return newNote;
  }

  void _textControllerListener() async {
    final note = _note;
    if (note == null) {
      return;
    }
    final text = _textController.text;
    await _noteService.updateNote(
      documentId: note.documentId,
      text: text,
    );
  }

  void _setupTextControllerListener() {
    _textController.removeListener(_textControllerListener);
    _textController.addListener(_textControllerListener);
  }

  void _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty() {
    final note = _note;
    if (_textController.text.isEmpty && note != null) {
      _noteService.deleteNote(documentId: note.documentId);
    }
  }

  void _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty() async {
    final note = _note;
    final text = _textController.text;
    if (note != null && text.isNotEmpty) {
      await _noteService.updateNote(
        documentId: note.documentId,
        text: text,
      );
    }
  }

  _initImagePath() async {
    setState(() {
      _isUploadingImage =
          true; // Set _isUploadingImage to true to prevent user interactions
    });

    final note = _note;
    final imagePath = await _noteService.pickAnImageAndGetUrl();
    if (note != null) {
      await _noteService.addImageToNote(
        documentId: note.documentId,
        imageUrl: imagePath,
      );
    }

    setState(() {
      _isUploadingImage = false;

// Set _isUploadingImage to false to allow user interactions
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty();
    _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty();
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.image),
        onPressed: () async {
          _initImagePath();
        },
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffFDF4F5),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.note_add,
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          size: 35,
        ),
        toolbarHeight: 100,
        title: const Text(
          'New Note',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontFamily: 'MainFont',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final text = _textController.text;
              if (_note == null || text.isEmpty) {
                await showCannotShareEmptyNoteDialog(context);
              } else {
                Share.share(text);
              }
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.share,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.save,
                color: Colors.black,
              ))
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: createOrGetExistingNote(context),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              _note = snapshot.data;
              _setupTextControllerListener();
              return AbsorbPointer(
                absorbing: _isUploadingImage,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      NoteViewTextFieldItem(textController: _textController),
                      if (_isUploadingImage)
                        Container(
                          width: 350,
                          height: 350,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            color: Colors.grey[300],
                          ),
                          child:
                              const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                        ),
                      if (_note?.imageUrl != null &&
                          !_imageDeleted &&
                          !_isLoadingImage)
                        GestureDetector(
                          onDoubleTap: () async {
                            final shouldDeleteImage =
                                await deleteImageDialog(context);
                            if (shouldDeleteImage) {
                              await _noteService.deleteImageInTheNote(
                                  documentId: _note!.documentId,
                                  imageUrl: _note!.imageUrl!);

                              setState(() {
                                _imageDeleted = true;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            child: Image.network(
                              _note!.imageUrl!,
                              width: 350,
                              loadingBuilder:
                                  (context, child, loadingProgress) {
                                if (loadingProgress == null) {
                                  _isLoadingImage = false;
                                  return child;
                                }
                                _isLoadingImage = true;
                                return Container(
                                  decoration:
                                      BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[300]),
                                  width: 350,
                                  height: 350,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                      value:
                                          loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes !=
                                                  null
                                              ? loadingProgress
                                                      .cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                                  loadingProgress
                                                      .expectedTotalBytes!
                                              : null,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 25,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );

            default:
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to use `setState` function to rebuild this page. But it didn't worked as i excepted.

Comment: maybe `loadingProgress` is never `null`, so its never returns the child